# Query for document in subcollection firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following structure of my database:

[image]

Inside the Location collection there is a document and in it there is Lat, Lon coordinates:

[image]

My final goal is to get all of the Lat, Lon coordinates of all users however im already stuck on how to get to Location collection if I dont know the document name where it is?

Is there some query that I can do to move straight inside to something like `WhereEqualTo("Lat")`?

To begin I tried the following:

```
    db.collection("Users").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        List<String> listID = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {

                            listID.add( doc.getId() );
                        }
```

However it returns me null list.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), as follows:

```
db.collectionGroup("Location").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                // ...
            }
        });
```

This runs a query across all collections names `Location` in your database.